# Parse Image + Parse httpRequest replacements — migrating from Parse Cloud Code to Parse Server on Node (Heroku / AWS / DO)

Tags: parse-platform, migration, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I found that when using the `parse-node` package, you can no longer use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`. I also know that Parse's `Image` object won't be available.

So far, I've been able to replace some Parse promises with native ones and use `axios` to make network requests.

However, I'm relatively new to Node, so I'm curious as to what are the most direct replacements for these, and how do I use them?

Comment: Still cant use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`. Any solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should still be able to use `Parse.Cloud.httpRequest`. But `axios` is a great library and it's a great idea to start using it if you want to learn nodejs. When it comes to the `parse-image` it has to be replaced. There is a library which claims 100% compatibilty, check it out [here](https://github.com/flovilmart/parse-image).